# Add active class to WordPress nav

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have pretty long nav here, which I have to import to WordPress.

```
<header class="small">
    <div class="yellow-stripe"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li>
                    <a href="aboutus">About us</a>
                    <ul class="sub-navigation">
                        <li><a href="">We are</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Our story</a></li>
                        <li><a href="why">Why Ledil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contacts-europe">Where</a></li>
                        <li><a href="management">Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Investors</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../news_all">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="../events_calendar">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="../qa">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <ul class="lang">
            <li class="active"><a href="">EN</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ES</a></li>
            <li><a href="">RUS</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-button">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>

</header>
```

It's made in HTML and now I have to import it to WordPress. I got WordPress to include the header, and to load the whole thing just fine, and it looks great on page, but I would need to add class="active" for bootstrap nav to current page  and to child pages too.

I found some answers by googling, but I didn't really get very far.

My function.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

    remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');

    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2);
    function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
        if( in_array('current_page_parent', $classes) ){
            $classes[] = 'active ';
        }
    return $classes;
    }
?>
```

I'm not really sure what I should try. I find the whole WordPress thing very strange.

There seems to be no current_page_item class here.. should I do anything special to enable it?

`li.current_page_parent a {}` won't work, nor will setting `class="<?php if (is_page('name-of-page')) echo 'active'; ?>"` inside a tags... goddamn WordPress...

Never mind.. I'm just bit slow.... I put  `class="<?php if (is_page('why')) echo 'active'; ?>"` inside every li element.

Comment: `li.current_page_item a {
    background-color: #34676b;
}`

Comment: tried this, and color: yellow; didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ends up here:
You should check if the page is active or the page is child of another page

```
<li class="<?php if (is_page('offices')) echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="/offices">Offices</a></li>
```

Checks if page is "offices" and

```
<li class="<?php if (is_page_child(143)) echo 'active'; ?> echo 'active'; ?>">
```

Checks if page is child page of page with id "143" and then echoes "active" inside class=" "